# Is NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey recursive

Tags: iphone, ios, backup

I have a huge tree of files and dirs for cache in my document directory.

As recommended, I'm going to use `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` for preventing iTunes from saving this data with the app.

Can I use it once on my root directory URL, as

```
[rootDirectoryURL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey" error:&error];
```

Or will I have to call it for each file?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yup, you can pass it a NSURL of the directory you want excluded.

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                  forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }

    return success;
}
```

And you can test any files if in doubt using

```
id flag = nil;
[URL getResourceValue: &flag
               forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
NSLog (@"NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey flag value is %@", flag)
```

Comment: Thanks, NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey seems to be recursive.

Comment: @Rog When I get the resource value for my exluded directory it returns 1 as expected, but when I test the files within they return 0 - is this to be expected? (I do not flag files added to my exluded dir with the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey since I already excluded the dir)

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, in my case just flagging the folder worked for all files and other folders inside it.

Comment: Not sure if anyone is still paying attention to this - but...  If I set this flag on a directory, then add contents to that directory later - do I need to apply this to the directory again - or are the current and future contents covered?

Comment: From my tests setting the flag on a folder doesn't affects its content. I'm testing in the simulator though, it may be different on real device.

Comment: getResourceValue returned YES result and the flag == nil after it. What's the problem?

Comment: @Michael Yes, the attribute is apparently applied recursively for existing files, so if one adds a new file later, that file is not skipped from backup.

Comment: @lef: That's wrong. If the attribute is applied to a folder, new files will be excluded automatically, no matter what their attribute is. From the docs: "If you have a large number of support files, you may store them in a custom subdirectory and apply the extended attribute to just the directory." - Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW17

Comment: @FrederikA.Winkelsdorf Sure it's bad sir. If you read the doc more in detail, you could also find this: "Some operations commonly made to user documents cause this property to be reset to false; " https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey

Comment: @lef: Well, yes - that's what "User Documents" is supposed to do. This directory is for (by) user generated content only and always included in iTunes/iCloud Backup. From your link "consequently, do not use this property on user documents". Also see my link again, paragraph "Use this directory to store user-generated content.". Probably best to rethink the design if one applies NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey to any file/folder under "User Documents". That's what "Application Support" is for. The Question I answered was, if the attribute needs to be re-applied for new files.

Comment: @lef: But you are right, if somebody tries to apply it to User Documents, it might fail. Didn't though of the case anybody trying to store excluded files there..

Comment: @FrederikA.Winkelsdorf I did not say one shell set the key for new files under the parent directory. It appears that after adding a new file, it's neccessary to apply the key to the parent folder again. Within the Application Support folder.

Comment: @lef: Do you have any additional information about this behavior? Did you submit a bug report to Radar? I didn't came across this, when using "Library/Application Support". If NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey is used on a subfolder AND it's outside of Documents folder, it must work. If not, it's a bug. Never had this problem when submitting Apps, but you may encounter a rare corner scenario, where e.g. a framework changes settings to your own folder(s).. Tried to find something here on SO, but didn't find anything related.

Comment: In latest I tried it on ios11 on simulator and it didnt work as mentioned above.
when I set attribute exclude from backup to YES on directory it doesn't apply to its existing files and subfolders recursively.

Answer (score 1):

From my tests (on a simulator), it is not recursive, and I've just had an app rejection because of too much data in Documents directory. Each folder directly in the Documents directory is flagged, so I guess the files inside them are not, even on a real device. But I also added new content in the folder, so I may just need to add the flag again.

So I'm using this recursive method now, and I add the flag on each new files added :

```
- (void) addSkipBackupAttributeToFolder:(NSURL*)folder
{
    [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:folder];

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSArray* folderContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[folder path] error:&error];

    for (NSString* item in folderContent)
    {
        NSString* path = [folder.path stringByAppendingPathComponent:item];
        [self addSkipBackupAttributeToFolder:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange thing, because I tested it last year: flagging a directory was really excluding every file under. However, I neither tested with ios ≥ 7 nor more than 2 subdirectory depth.

Comment: It may be recursive on real devices, as my app ma have been rejected because of the new files added in the folder.

Comment: In one app case I was working on - I also got rejected because I used Documents directory. Then I moved everything to cache (as everything was re-downloadable), but still - it appeared that some stuff gets written in documents directory. (By checking phone iCloud memory backups..) I don't know what it was (maybe some 3rd party framework), but I simply added "feature" to delete documents directory every time app launched.. and then App finally got into appstore.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a swift version of the accepted answer:

```
func addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(URL: NSURL) -> Bool {
    assert(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(URL.path!))
    var success: Bool = true

    do {
        try URL.setResourceValue(NSNumber(bool: true), forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)
    } catch {
        success = false
        print("Error excluding \(URL.lastPathComponent) from backup: \(error)")
    }

    return success
}
```