# Is NSFileManager.SetSkipBackupAttribute() also working for (recursive) paths?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, backup, nsfilemanager

I would like to exclude a whole hierarchy of files and folders from the backup using

```
NSFileManager.SetSkipBackupAttribute()
```

The [documentation](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSFileManager.SetSkipBackupAttribute%28System.String,System.Boolean%29) is about "files". Can I also pass a path and all files and folders under that path - also those ones added afterwards - won't be backed up either or do I have to set the attribute on every individual file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like stated in the documentation the underlying API used (except for iOS 5.0.1) is `NSUrlIsExcludedFromBackupKey` and according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14376883/220643) it is recursive.