# Codename one: Want to set allowBackup = false on all platform

Tags: codenameone

I want to set property **allowBackup=false** on all platform including IOS.
So for that which property should I set in codename one ?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

On Android this is just a global build hint but in iOS this is a bit harder. You would need to use a native interface with code like this: [Disable backup of documents folder and all its sub folders on icloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056556/disable-backup-of-documents-folder-and-all-its-sub-folders-on-icloud)

For Android you can just use the build hint `android.allowBackup=false`.

Answer (score -1):

In Flutter, you can use the `flutter_secure_storage` package to disable app data backup on iOS. This package provides the ability to store data securely in Keychain and disable its backup.
To disable the backup of data stored in `flutter_secure_storage`, you need to manually set the `kSecAttrAccessible` property to `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly`.

It might look like this:

```
final FlutterSecureStorage _secureStorage = const FlutterSecureStorage(iOptions:IOSOptions(accessibility: KeychainAccessibility.first_unlock_this_device) ,
    aOptions: AndroidOptions(encryptedSharedPreferences: true),
  );
```