# MacOS: programmatically prevent backup of file to iCloud?

Tags: macos, icloud, nsfilemanager, xattr

I am dealing with MacOS, not iOS, and I want to ensure that a file is not backed up to iCloud (if iCloud is enabled). How is that done?

Comment: I think you can add a `.nosync` to the end of the filename and it should not upload

Answer (score 1):

You could use [NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlisexcludedfrombackupkey?language=objc):

```
NSURL* url = //...
[[url setResourceValue:@YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:nil];
```

It sets `com.apple.metadata:com_apple_backup_excludeItem` extended attribute on files and directories.

Comment: But doesn't that affect only the NSURL object? I would think that to change the file itself, it would require using a method of NSFileManager.

Comment: No. It is confusing as normally `NSURL` doesn't work like that. But this will set the extended attribute above on the file or directory pointed at by the `NSURL`, and exclude it from iCloud backups.

Comment: Your question is actually a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056556/disable-backup-of-documents-folder-and-all-its-sub-folders-on-icloud